# Verifying webhook authenticity using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webhooks, zendesk

I am migrating some code to Java Spring Boot and using Zendesk Webhooks. The webhooks requests have two headers

```
X-Zendesk-Webhook-Signature - the main signature
X-Zendesk-Webhook-Signature-Timestamp - the timestamp used to verify the signature
```

Also there is a secret key. Until now I was able to test webhook and it successfully reached my @RestController but now I want to validate it that its coming from Zendesk.
Ref - https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/event-connectors/webhooks/verifying/